# Netlogo: how to round heading into 90 180 270 360 only

Tags: netlogo

I am currently building a model for people walking on a certain path (road patches, color = white). The agents' movement will only be limited on the white patch and when they encounter black patch they will rotate 180 deg.

The problem I found was when I tried to set the heading of the agents. I want the heading to walk to the nearest red patch (destination), but when I use:

## 1

> set heading towards min-one-of patches with [pcolor = red ] [ distance myself ] <

the agents wont move from their patch. It turned out that the "heading" generated by the above code has the value of -360 to 360 with decimals in it. The walking procedure that I have built only allows heading with multiplies of 90 (-360, -180 ... 90, 180, 270, 360). This is the full code for my walking procedure:

## 2

```
globals [ flagl flagr ]

ask agents [

;reset flag
    set flagr 0
    set flagl 0

; check and note if there is a path on the left or the right
      ask patch-left-and-ahead 90 1 [if (pcolor = white ) [set flagl 1]]
      ask patch-right-and-ahead 90 1 [if (pcolor = white ) [set flagr 1]
        ]

;in T-junction, decide to turn left or right (random)
      if((flagl = 1) and (flagr = 1))
      [
        ifelse random 100 > 50
        [set heading heading - 90]
        [set heading heading + 90]
      ]

;if it's only applicable to turn right, then turn right
      if((flagl = 0) and (flagr = 1)) [set heading heading + 90]

;if it's only applicable to turn left, then turn right
      if((flagl = 1) and (flagr = 0)) [set heading heading - 90]

;return if there's no mor path
      if [pcolor] of patch-at-heading-and-distance heading 1 = black [rt 180]

;agent movement
      **;face min-one-of patches with [pcolor = red ] [ distance myself ]**
       fd 1

;stopping procedure
if [pcolor] of patch-here = red [fd 0]
]]
```

I tried to round the heading generated by #1 like this:

```
let direction heading towards min-one-of patches with [pcolor = red ] [ distance myself ]
if direction != mod 90
set direction 90 * round(arah/ 90)
```

However it gives error notice since "let" command cannot take that kind of input.

This is the screenshot of the map I have built:
[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn65D.png)

Any help to solve this problem is hugely appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This might get you started- with minimal checking it seems to do the trick, but you will probably want to check for exceptions.

The `cardinal-4` reporter takes whatever input is given and checks if the modulo is equal to 0. If not, it will check if modulo is less than/equal to 45- if so, subtracts that value from the direction (`dir`). If modulo is greater than 45, the subtract the modulo from the direction and add 90.

The `check` procedure just prints the reporter output for the values listed.

```
to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
end

to-report cardinal-4 [ heading-input ]
  let dir heading-input
  let remain dir mod 90
  if remain != 0 [
    ifelse remain <= 45 [
      set dir dir - remain
    ]
    [
      set dir dir - remain + 90
    ]
  ]  
  report dir
end
```

**Edit**: improved `check` procedure:

```
to check
  let testVals [ -361 -359 -271 -269 -181 -179 -91 -89 -1 0 1 89 91 179 181 269 271 359 360 361 ]
  print map [ i -> ( word i " becomes " cardinal-4 i "\n" ) ] testVals
end
```